# Calculating Christoffel Symbols

Tags: tensors, astronomy

I am totally new in the astrophysics field and I need to calculate Christoffel symbols for a model. The line element for the FLRW metric and the geodesic equation is given below: [image]                                    [image]
Can anyone please help me by providing the directions that how can I calculate Christoffel symbols by mathematica from there? How can I calculate the metric tensor or what will be the steps? Expecting experts help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many packages out there that help with this type of calculation. For example xAct http://www.xact.es